# How to change status code in http header in yii2 RESTful api

Tags: rest, yii2, http-headers

I am using `Yii2` for restful api and its working fine. However I want to change status in header. Suppose I want to access users ID 13 record and this id not found in database so my api response will be

```
{"name":"Not Found","message":"","code":0,"status":404}
```

but in `header status` is `200` I need same status in header as in api response that is `404` if record not found. How I can change the header status according to api response

Answer (score 12):

```
Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 404;
```

Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html

The guide also suggest to throw errors to change the status codes.

```
throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Comment: Yes but It will change only in in the api response but not change the http headers

Comment: @ArslanButt you may be experiencing some other problem.  Those two are the same.  The api response is over http, and it has one set of response headers and one response status code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the controller to throw a 404 instead of setting the response code. You can add this in your controller action after finding the model.

```
if ( !$model) {
    throw new HttpException(404, Yii::t('app','Record not found.'));
}
```

This will work with a JSON API or regular HTML.